# MVC 4 Bundle QueryString Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have MVC 4 project and I set Bundle config, then when run the project. Click Show Source on Google Chrome, I see,

Content/css?v=42vVIeLLwfJkSHVR7RjQehV5VVwDvOhprAczcjnTBiU1

Then I test my website performance on GTMetrix. And says me, 
**Remove query strings from static resources** for ?v=

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: That's a cachebuster URL. If your CSS changes, the querystring will make sure that the browser gets the latest version instead of reusing a cached version. So you may be able to ignore the GTMetrix message. Does your CSS change every once in a while?

Comment: I solve my problem. And thank you so much for your attention danludwig. I solved problem below, <link href="@BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css", false)" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 1):

The `v` querystring is a dynamic cache buster, a hash of the file contents.

This is great for performance as you can cache the bundle for a year (default) and any changes to the contents will update the cache buster.

*It's quite ironic that GTMetrix are reporting against this.*

However if you really need to you can remove the hash cache-buster by setting `false` for the 2nd parameter of [`ResolveBundleUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecollection.resolvebundleurl(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
@BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css", false)
```

If this is just to please GTMetrix however, I would refrain from doing this.